# Polymer: need paragraph text to break on lines

Tags: styles, polymer, nl2br

I've tried a couple different ways of doing this but I can't seem to get polymer to print the html or the breaks in the lines of the paragraphs (Need lines to break!). Pulling data via json call.

```
<div layout horizontal left>

<story-text storytext="{{ resp[0].body.und[0].value }}"></story-text>

</div>
```

OR?

```
<div layout horizontal left>

<div>{{ resp[0].body.und[0].value }}</div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost gave up. I searched and searched and found this:
https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-html
Is working!